# Проблема при адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, drupal

Доброе утро, пытаюсь сделать адаптивную верстку на сайт и столкнулся с такой проблемой, блок что идет справа не отображается на мобильных устройствах т.к не хватает места, передо мной есть такая разметка:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="wc">
                    <?php print render($page['topmenu']); ?>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="top" class="wc">
                <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
                <div id="slider"><?php print render($page['slider']); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="inside" class="wc">
            <div id="sidebar"><?php print render($page['sidebar']); ?></div>
            <div id="content"><?php print render($page['content']); ?></div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer_content" class="wc">
                &COPY; 2017 POLITPLAKAT.ORG
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.masonry-item { 
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
 }

 .masonry-item a {
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height: 1.5;
 }

.masonry-item img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Как заставить блок справа отобразиться ниже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как использовал:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="wc">
                    <?php print render($page['topmenu']); ?>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="top" class="wc">
                <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
                <div id="slider"><?php print render($page['slider']); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="inside" class="wc">
            <div id="sidebar"><?php print render($page['sidebar']); ?></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div id="content"><?php print render($page['content']); ?></div>
        </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footer_content" class="wc">
                &COPY; 2017 POLITPLAKAT.ORG
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем тебе row, если ты колонки не задаешь?

Comment: Alex78191 соль в том, что нет смысла задавать колонки судя по всему, раз в контенте лежат не только пикчи но и переход на другие страницы, может это можно сделать посредству медиа-запросов?

Comment: Колонки как раз и используют медиа запросы , изучите сетку bootstrap

Comment: Alex78191 , может покажете на моём примере как это реализовать?
С сеткой я знаком, она не работает в моём случае, проверял.

Comment: напишите как использовали

Comment: Блок справа это #content?

Comment: @Alex78191 в вопрос прикрепил, то есть я хотел что-бы в extra small 1 пикча стояла в ряд, а в medium по 2 в ряд

Comment: @Alex78191 Да, это #content

Comment: @Alex78191 сам верстаю сайты с применением сетки, а как быть тут понятия не имею.

Comment: Зачем столько классов и вложений одно в другое, у вас сайт простее простого, а делаете такую чушь. И еще кое, что: советую писать так `<?=render($page['content'])?>` за место `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`.

Comment: @And спасибо, сейчас исправлю.

А как быть с картинками?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyGROv